# How can I merge 2 empty lines into one? Like cat -s

Tags: c

how can I merge 2 empty lines into one? Like `cat -s`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int c;
  
    FILE *file = fopen("2.txt", "r");
    while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF) {
        putc(c, stdout);             
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: juste save previous line and when this line is empty and previous is empty use `continue;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a modified version that implements `cat -s`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c, last_c = '\n', has_empty = 0;

    FILE *file = fopen("2.txt", "r");
    if (file != NULL) {
        while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF) {
            if (last_c == '\n' && c == '\n') {
                if (has_empty) {
                    //has_empty = 0;
                    continue;
                }
                has_empty = 1;
            } else {
                has_empty = 0;
            }
            putchar(c);
            last_c = c;
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to only collapse 2 empty lines into one, uncomment the `//has_empty = 0;` statement.